# Как сгрупировать текст по длине в отдельные групппы по похожести длины

Tags: javascript, строки, сортировка

Пожалуйста,подскажите в виде псевдокода или текста, полное решение не нужно,сам сделаю.
 как сортировать по длине текст разбив его на группы по похожести длины

Нужно сортировать по длине что я уже сделал.Потом проверить насколько процентов отличается длина строк.
Если при сортировке по длине длина отдельных строк превышает на определенное кол-во с символов нужно добавить разделитель.

*Главный вопрос как узнать это кол-во символов? И как сгруппировать элементы по похожести длин?*
я сделал только подготовительную работу, потому что у меня привычка делать что-то полностью зная как это сделать, а не пытаться найти ответ в ходе работы

тут можно взять например число-минимум например если в границах двух трех символов тогда объединяем в 1 групп по длине.
однако такой вариант будет работать только в этом примере, а мне нужно чтобы работало в разных случаях а значит разница должна вычисляться автоматически.

Мне нужен хотя бы совет как это сделать.Если совет будет хороший он будет считаться решением

```js
String.prototype.lines = function() {
  return this.split(/\r*\n/);
}

function percentage(partialValue, totalValue) {
  return (100 * partialValue) / totalValue;
}

var stringArray = document.getElementById('textarea').value.split('\n');
var count = stringArray.length;

//я сделал только подготовительную работу, потому что у меня прывычка делать что-то полностью зная как это сделать, а не пытаться найти ответ в ходе работы



var sortArray = [];
sortArray = stringArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  //как сортировать по длине текст разбив его на группы по похожести длины?

  return (a.length - b.length);
});

console.log(sortArray);
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">
342 Alvin Road
Ducksburg
texts text
text text texts12
other texts texts
5
looooooooooooooooong text
</textarea>
<textarea id="val"></textarea>
```

Нужно вот такое:

```
    -----------------отступ 1 группы по длине
    5
    -----------------отступ 2 группы по длине
    texts t
    Ducksburg
    -----------------отступ 3 группы по длине (разница с предыдущим 4 символа)
    342 Alvin Road
    -----------------отступ 4 группы по длине (разница с предыдущим 5 символов)
    other text text texts12
    other other texts texts
    other other texts texts1
    -----------------отступ 5 группы по длине(разница с предыдущим 15 символов)
    looooooooooooooooooooooooongoooong text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/** Сортировка и группировка строк текста по их длинам
 * @param {string} text - исходный текст
 * @param {number} threshold - пороговое значение относительной разницы длин, для создания новой группы
 * @returns {string[][]} массив групп строк
 */
function foo(text, threshold) {
  const sorted = text.split('\n').sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length); 
  if (sorted.length < 2) return [[sorted]]; 
  const result = []; 
  let curLen = 0,
      group  = [sorted[0]]; 
  for (let prvLen, diff, i = 1; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    prvLen = curLen || sorted[i - 1].length; 
    curLen = sorted[i].length; 
    diff   = (curLen - prvLen) / curLen; 
    if (diff > threshold) {
      group.length && result.push([...group]); 
      group = []; 
    }
    group.push(sorted[i]); 
  }
  result.push([...group]); 
  return result; 
}

const txt = `342 Alvin Road
Ducksburg
texts text
text text texts12
other texts texts
5
looooooooooooooooong text`; 
let testResult = foo(txt, 0.1);   // порог 0.1 == разница >10% от большей длины
console.log(JSON.stringify(testResult));
```

Comment: Отличное решение, в этот раз уже точно решающее эту задачу. Выразить разницу в процентах, как раз то что нужно. Я уже и не думал что кто-то напишет еще, спасибо.

Comment: @xopayas1, всегда пожалуйста :) Но сразу оговорюсь, что с разными аргументами я не проверял этот код - автотесты очень желательны.

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = [
  'car',
  'car',
  'dog',
  'water',
  'dodge',
  'shift',
  'space',
  'automation',
  'abarkadabra',
  'lolekecheburek',
  'whomalahymatat',
  'keyboard',
  'human'
];



var result = [];

function groupedByLength(lengthDifference) {

  let uses = [];

  for (const value of words) {

    console.log(value, uses);

    if (uses.indexOf(value) == -1) {

      let maybe = words.filter(v => 
        v.length == value.length || 
        v.length == value.length + lengthDifference || 
        v.length == value.length - lengthDifference);


      uses.push(...maybe);

      result.push({
        group: result.length + 1,
        value: maybe,
      })
    }
  }
}


groupedByLength(2);

console.log(result);
```

Как то так

Comment: Большое спасибо за решение. Все работает как надо. Я даже не надеялся получить полное решение, и хотел хотя-бы подсказку.

Comment: По правде говоря вы помогли найти решение. Ваше решение решает вопрос как я и говорил, нужно вставлять нужное число отличий. Чтобы все действительно заработало как надо я добавил цикл и прошелся по нескольким вариантам отличий и автоматически выбрал наиболее подходящее по отношению.